# G, a finite abelian and cyclic group, isomorphic to set of homomorphisms of G into C\{0}

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I am having trouble with the following problem, taken from Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* 2nd Edition:

> If $G$ is an abelian group, let $\hat G$ be the set of all homomorphisms of $G$
> into the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication.
> If, $\phi_1,\phi_2\in \hat G$, define $\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2$ by $\phi_1 \cdot \phi_2(g) = \phi_1(g) \phi_2 (g)$ for all $g \in G.$
>
> Show that, given $G$ is also finite and cyclic, $\hat G$ is cyclic and $G$ and $\hat G$ are isomorphic.

I have already proved that $\hat G$ is abelian and that for $\phi \in \hat G$ we have $\phi(g)$ a root of unity for every $g \in G$.

My approach:

Since $G$ and $\hat G$ are both finite and abelian, we have $G=A_1 \times ...\times A_n$ and $\hat G=B_1 \times ... \times B_m$ where each $A_i$ and $B_i$ are cyclic.

Now I want to show that $n=m$ and that $A_i=B_i$ for each $i=1,..n$.

Is this a proper approach? If so, any suggestions on how I can go about this?

Comment: Isn't the problem assuming that $G$ has only one cyclic factor?

Comment: It will be easier to show your groups have the same order, and both are cyclic.

Comment: @WillDana oh right, of course, and that immediately shows that $\hat G$ is cyclic, since it is abelian and each of its elements is a root of unity.

Comment: @SteveD How should I start to prove they have the same order?

Comment: Every map is defined by where it sends a generator of $G$. How many complex numbers can be the image of such a generator?

Answer (score 1):

First note that for a finite cyclic group $G$ any homomophism to any other group $H$ is known if the image of a generator $g$ of $G$ is known since the images of $g^2,g^3, \ldots$ can be calculated. As you stated correctly the images in this case are all roots of unity. If these are taken as the image of a certain homomophism what have  these elements in common (w.r.t. their order)? What can you say about an arbitrary homomorphism w.r.t. a fixed homomorphism that maps $g$ to a primitive root of unity?